# Recommendations for a C implementation of a regex parser

Tags: c, regex, parsing, recommendation-engine

I'm thinking about implementing a regular expression parser in a C library I'm developing. Now, the question is: is there any open source code that I could use verbatim or with as few changes as possible? My expectations regarding the code are:

- it needs to be written in C (not C++)
- it needs to compile under gcc, mingw, M$VC
- it mustn't depend on any third party or OS-specific headers/libraries (ie, everything needed to compile it must be readily available with a base installation of gcc, mingw, M$VC
- it would be nice if it used Perl-compatible regex syntax (like PCRE in PHP).
- ideally, the code should be as compact as possible

Are there any ready-made solutions that you could recommend? I was looking at PCRE for C and it looks like it has everything that's available in PHP (which rules), but the size (1.4MB DL) is a bit intimidating. Do you think it's a solid bet? Or are there other options worth considering?

[EDIT]

The library I'm developing is open source, BSD licence.

Comment: What license will you be releasing your library under?

Comment: PHP is built ontop of C. I wouldn't be surprised if PHP uses PCRE for C.

Comment: @Jefromi: thanks for asking about it, I forgot to add that piece of info. I've updated the question.

Comment: @Benedict: I believe it does: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php :)

Comment: M$? Seriously? That used to be cool like a decade ago.

Comment: @Rei: I don't even have Visual Studio installed, but the library has a lot of users that use M$VC, so the lib's main developer takes care everything works OK on M$VC too.

Comment: @mingos, I suspect that Rei is commenting on the use of `$` as a slur against MS. Yes they charge for many of their products. Get over it.

Comment: Oh, Sorry, I didn't get that. I always write "M$" and "M$VC", it's sort of an old habit, not "being cool" or trying to protest against them making money. I've outgrown that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PCRE is pretty much the de facto standard of regex implementations (for a good reason). Don't worry about the size, it's big because regex implementations are complicated. Just use it anyway.

Comment: Recommending bad code because it's "de facto standard" and because *foo* is "complicated" (hint: it's not) is not good advice.

Comment: I didn't recommend it because it was complicated. I stated that PCRE was "pretty much the de facto standard". I don't think it's bad code.

Answer (score 7):

PCRE is so big because regular expressions are *hard*. And most of it is documentation and support code anyways; it's much smaller when compiled into object code.

Comment: Regular expressions are not hard; PCRE is just bloated and last I checked it was `O(2^n)`. A complete POSIX regex implementation should weigh in at less than 10k (x86 machine code); I'm not sure about Perl-style regex (which isn't even a regular language) since it has all kinds of odd extensions but I seriously doubt there's a legitimate reason for PCRE to be as large as it is.

Comment: The reason PCRE is O(2^n) is because it supports perl style regexes, (that support back-references). Have you written a backtracking regex implementation? Who are you to say that it is not hard or how big it should be?

Comment: Obviously with back-references it's `O(2^n)`, but last I checked it also had very bad asymptotic behavior (perhaps just `O(n^2)` or `O(nm)` though) for many purely regular, non-back-reference-containing expressions.

Comment: As for how big it should be, I glanced at TRE (which although it uses asymptotically-efficient algorithms, has rather bloated code), and saw that the total `size(1)` of the relevant `.o` files was about 19k. Having read the code in some detail before, I quickly estimated that you could shave off roughly half the code size and improve performance at the same time (much of it by simplifying data structures and isolating failure-cases to single checks ahead of time). That's where my 10k estimate came from.

Comment: TRE says it has O(nm^2). Suddenly O(nm) doesn't sound so bad. I admit the case for TRE is quite compelling, but I don't think PCRE is a bad choice.

Comment: I wrote `O(nm)` by mistake and it was too late to edit the comment when I noticed.

Answer (score 6):

[RE2](http://code.google.com/p/re2/), the Google regexp implementation does a match in linear time (`O(n)` if `n` is the length of the string), PCRE and most other regexp engines run in exponential time at worst case. Another noteworthy `O(n)` regexp matcher is [flex](https://github.com/westes/flex), but it needs all possible regexps at compile time. If you are looking for something smaller than PCRE, look at the regexp matcher in [busybox](http://www.busybox.net/), or the pattern matcher in [lua](http://www.lua.org/ftp/).

Comment: @mingos, can you not wrap it for consumption by C code even though the guts are written in C++? All of the compilers you name make C++ available, after all.

Comment: Not really. The library in question is not my property, I'm just a co-maintainer. The policy is rather strict: all code is written in C and then a C++ wrapper is added on top of that. I'm not really in the power to influence that.

Answer (score 3):

You might try TRE if you're happy with POSIX regex syntax. If you want Perl syntax, Google has a new implementation worth checking out.